# little question about a notation of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

In algebra we often consider the ring of polynomials $K[x]$ with coefficients in a field $K$ for example. If you write out a polynomial $p\in K[x]$, sometimes I see different things: $p(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^na_ix^i$ and $p=\sum\limits_{i=0}^na_ix^i$. Furthermore I'm often not sure if I have to write $p\in K[x]$ or $p(x)\in K[x]$. What is the correct variant now? I think, if you write $p\in K[x]$ and $p=\sum\limits_{i=0}^na_ix^i$ it is just formal. So you always wirte $p\in K[x]$. But if you want to calculate something with polynomials, you write $p(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^na_ix^i$ I would say. But I'm not sure...

Comment: Just remember to distinguish between polynomial and the polynomial function!

Answer (score 0):

In practice, the two mean the same thing.

Being somewhat more precise (or pedantic, perhaps), $K[x]$ is a ring; an element of $K[x]$ might be, for example, $p$. When you *evaluate* $p$ at some element $t$ of that ring, you write $p(t)$. So for example, you can "evaluate" $p$ at $1$, giving $p(1)$, or you can "evaluate" it at $x$, giving $p(x)$.

You can think of evaluation at $t$ as the image of $p\in K[x]$ under the homomorphism
\begin{equation*}
  K[x]\to K[t] : x\mapsto t.
\end{equation*}
Note that if $t\in K$, then $K[t] = K$ and you recover the usual definition of evaluation of a polynomial at a value.